# How to properly format pyspark logfile

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, cmd, pyspark

I am trying to implement logging in python.Here is mycode.I am trying to get console outputs on the same log file.I am using python 2.7

```
def cal_val(i):
    logger.info("added valu is {}".format(i+1))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(filename="sample1.log",format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',level=logging.INFO,datefmt='%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S')
    # Creating an object
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    for i in range(1,5):
        logger.info("First valu is {}".format(i))
        cal_val(i)
    shecmd="spark-submit C:\PycharmProjects\\Finaltst\\from_dt_to_dt.py --executor-memory 5G --total-executor-cores 2"
    logger.info("Executing shell command------>")
    logger.info(shecmd)
    proc=subprocess.Popen(shecmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,shell=True)
    for line in proc.stdout:
        logger.info(line)
```

Now I am getting results in the logfile but the formatting is not proper
[image]

As you can see in the highlighed part along with the logger I have provided in the code,It is taking logger for console also resulting lines  like below which is not in proper format.It is also adding b' at starting of line and \r,\n at the end of the line

```
2020-08-29_12:19:23 INFO     b'20/08/29 12:19:23 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: System\r\n'
```

How to avoid this.I want to write logs in a manner that it should look like below
[image]

Is there any way where instaed of below line

```
for line in proc.stdout:
        logger.info(line)
```

I can just write something like print() which will only print console outputs in the same logfile??

Answer (score 0):

As the "line" you get from Popen stdout is type of bytes, you need convert it to string type.

```
for line in proc.stdout:
    logger.info(line.decode())
```

Comment: it is removing \r,\n,but the output still comes with levels(INFO,DEBUG).I want a way to elemeinate that